# ms Access: How to get field values from query in function call inside of same query without passing it as function arguments

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query called `qryA` using a custom function called `getCoefC` to get a specific coefficient value from a table based on the values of some fields in that same query. The coefficients are then to be used in calculated fields within a given query.
The way it works right now is that the function takes those field values indirectly as arguments and passes them into an sql string inside the function.

The function `getCoefC` is this:

```
Public Function getCoefC(strrecid As Integer, strchemid As Integer, strcoefid As 
Integer) As Double
'***************************************************************************
'Purpose: Search for specific Coefficient on chemical level
'Inputs: RecipeID; CoefficientID; ChemicalID
'Outputs: CoefficientValue for Chemical level
'***************************************************************************

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim numcoef As Double

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    'sql string containing function inputs
    strsql = "SELECT tblLinkCoefficients.RecipeID, tblLinkCoefficients.ChemicalID," _
    & "tblLinkCoefficients.CoefficientID, tblLinkCoefficients.CoefficientValue " _
    & "FROM tblLinkCoefficients " _
    & "WHERE (((tblLinkCoefficients.RecipeID)=" & strrecid & ") " _
    & "AND ((tblLinkCoefficients.ChemicalID)=" & strchemid & ") " _
    & "AND ((tblLinkCoefficients.CoefficientID)=" & strcoefid & "))"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    'Check if recordset is not empty, then set coef value
    If rs.EOF = False Then
        numcoef = rs("CoefficientValue")
    Else
        numcoef = 0
    End If

    'Reset recordset
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    getCoefC = numcoef

End Function
```

The query `qryA` I am using looks like this:

```
SELECT tblProducts.ProductName, tblRecipes.RecipeName, tblChemicals.ChemicalName, 
tblRecipesChemicalsLink.WeightMeasureBefore, tblRecipesChemicalsLink.WeightMeasureAfter, 
tblRecipes.RecipeID, tblRecipesChemicalsLink.ChemicalID, getCoefC([tblRecipes].[RecipeID],
[tblRecipesChemicalsLink].[ChemicalID],23) AS CCoef
FROM (tblProducts INNER JOIN tblRecipes ON tblProducts.ProductID = tblRecipes.ProductID) 
INNER JOIN (tblChemicals INNER JOIN tblRecipesChemicalsLink ON tblChemicals.ChemicalID = 
tblRecipesChemicalsLink.ChemicalID) ON tblRecipes.RecipeID = 
tblRecipesChemicalsLink.RecipeID;
```

The isolated syntax for the function as in above example either directly in sql or the query tool looks like this atm:

```
CCoef: getCoefC([tblRecipes].[RecipeID];[tblRecipesChemicalsLink].[ChemicalID];23)
```

The output I am getting is this:

| ProductName | RecipeName | ChemicalName | WeightMeasureBefore | WeightMeasureAfter | RecipeID | ChemicalID | CCoef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | Recipe A Product A | Chemical A | 0 | 0 | 38 | 30 | 10 |
| Product A | Recipe A Product A | Chemical B | 0 | 0 | 38 | 31 | 0 |
| Product A | Recipe A Product A | Chemical C | 0 | 0 | 38 | 32 | 0 |
| Product A | Recipe A Product A | Chemical D | 0 | 0 | 38 | 33 | 0 |

My issue is the length of the syntax. I would like to be able to use the function to access numerous coefficients from within the query in an easy way. The function call is just too long and makes the syntax difficult to wrap your head around. I want to get the same output but with a simplified function call akin to ideally:

```
CCoef: getCoefC(23)
```

Or less idealy:

```
CCoef: getCoefC(RecipeID;ChemicalID;23)
```

Just hard coding the table references from the function argument into the sql string's WHERE clause results in an `error 3061: too few parameters`. Using `RecipeID` alone doesn't work because there are obviously multiple tables with a field of that name. I was hoping there might be a way to access the row values in the query themselves somehow without using the table references or to somehow grab them from within the function but I haven't figured out how to, so I'd appreciate any help. The goal is to have the function call be as simple as possible, thx. Maybe I am also thinking about this in the wrong way and there is a more elegant solution, idk. This is what I came up with so far.

Comment: There is no way. If you need arguments, you must specify them.

Comment: So you just want to pass 23 to the function?  I'm not understanding how CCoef: getCoefC(23) is going to be efficient in this context.

Comment: It's mostly about readability. If I have a longer formula that calls different coefficients multiple times, having the full syntax looks messy and is difficult to interpret at first glance, especially inside an sql statement. Imagine I use SWITCH or something to differentiat formulas by product or chemical level on top of that. That gets messy real quick, so I wanted to minimize any bloat I can. The first two arguments of the function will never take any other reference as input, but the values obviously change by the row...